# Set Padding Google Map Android without moving buttons, only marker

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When I select a marker, I want the camera to move to focus it. But I don't want the marker to appear in the center of the view (default behaviour); instead of this, I want it to appear some pixels below.

The only way I have found to do this, is:

```
googleMap.setPadding(0, 500, 0, 0);
```

This works, but the problem is that also moves down "My Location" button, and other buttons of the map view.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onMarkerClickListener for the map and animate the transition yourself by using CameraUpdateFactory.

```
/** Called when the user clicks a marker. */
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    Map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatlng, 50));

    /** Return true here to consume the event*/
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This will set the center of the camera on a new LatLng point... But I don't want to move it with coordinates, because the size of the movement is very small. Would be great to move it only a few pixels. Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: I'm confused...
The amount of distance you are moving the camera is irrelevant.  Just add/subtract a few seconds from the lat and lng supplied by the marker's location to have the camera focus slightly off center of the natural resting point of the marker.